Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan
Once I run terraform Apply and try to run terraform Plan, it always detects a configuration Drift. I am getting the following error. this is happening all the time only I apply Plan after the apply. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
`Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan`

`Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:

  # module.this.azurerm_storage_account.this has changed
  ~ resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
        id                                = "/subscriptions/d4gbaaf88-4ygX2-4tg3-9611-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg-ifhq/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stieiq"
        name                              = "stiggiq"
        tags                              = {
            "dept"  = "IT"
            "env"   = "Prod"
            "owner" = "Smith"
        }
        # (39 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ network_rules {
          ~ default_action             = "Allow" -> "Deny"
          ~ ip_rules                   = [
              + "125.125.125.1",
            ]
          ~ virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
              + "/subscriptions/d4gbaaf88-4ygX2-4tg3-9611-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg-ifhq/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-rfeiq/subnets/snet-gerq",
            ]
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
        }

        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }


Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include actions to undo or respond to these changes.`

variable "network_rules" {
  type = object({
    bypass                     = optional(set(string), [])
    default_action             = optional(string, "Deny")
    ip_rules                   = optional(set(string), [])
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = optional(set(string), [])
    private_link_access = optional(list(object({
      endpoint_resource_id = string
      endpoint_tenant_id   = optional(string)
    })))
    timeouts = optional(object({
      create = optional(string)
      delete = optional(string)
      read   = optional(string)
      update = optional(string)
    }))
  })
  default = {}

 tags = {
    env   = "Prod"
    owner = "Smith"
    dept  = "IT"
  }


How are you providing the value to the said variable?

In your Terraform configuration, you can utilize the ignore_changes lifecycle argument to avoid the detection and reversal of external modifications to storage account network rules. This ensures that any external changes do not impact your Terraform plan when you execute it after running terraform apply. @shameera2008

@VinayB If i add the ignore_changes Meta argument, it will not detect any real configuration change on the env. Do you know why this is happening, even without making any changes ?

are you using tfvars file to define the values for the variables? @shameera2008

@VinayB nope. i directly adding them via example.

This may be during the first Terraform apply, you might not have defined the virtual_network_subnet_ids and left them blank. Then, you ran the Terraform apply. In the second Terraform plan run, you included a value for the variable with the subnet ID, which was detected as changes during the plan, as mentioned in the query. @shameera2008

If changes occur in the portal (outside of Terraform state), you may also encounter the error mentioned. @shameera2008

you can use this  lifecycle {
ignore_changes = [network_rules]
}
so that you can overcome the the drift issue was mentioned.

Please provide the terraform used to create this.
